# При установке npm install talib выдает кучу ошибок

Tags: npm

Всем привет.

я пытаюсь установить npm install или npm install talib мне выдает лог файл с ошибками. 
Пытаюсь обновить ноду до более свежей версии, тоже не получается.

Кто подскажет, что нужно сделать или как правильно установить без ошибок пакеты, заранее благодарен.

[debug.log](https://dropmefiles.com/ecIXQ)

Comment: может прав не хватает, sudo? Или `npm -g install-local`

Comment: Спасибо. Пытаюсь различными способами решить проблему. Обязательно отпишусь.